# SSL certificate not trusted by other browsers in mobile devices except for google chrome

Tags: node.js, ssl

I just published a website hosted on a vps using node js express. I have the certificates from Let's encrypt. THe website works well in all browsers when using a PC, but on mobile devices it only works in Google Chrome. It's not trusted on Safary , Firefox, etc. I've tried using ssllabs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=uniroad.co.za) and it says my website is trusted by Mozilla, Apple, Android, Java, and Windows.Thanks in advance. [When using Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchnT.jpg)

```
const port = 443;
const fs=require('fs');
const privateKey=fs.readFileSync('C:/Certbot/live/uniroad.co.za/privkey.pem');
const certificate=fs.readFileSync('C:/Certbot/live/uniroad.co.za/cert.pem');
const 
chainLines=fs.readFileSync('C:/Certbot/live/uniroad.co.za/fullchain.pem','utf8').split("\n");

var cert = [];
var caa = [];
chainLines.forEach(function(line) {
cert.push(line);
if (line.match(/-END CERTIFICATE-/)) {
caa.push(cert.join("\n"));
cert = [];
}
});

let options = {
key:privateKey,
cert:certificate,
ca:caa,
dotfiles: "ignore",
etag: true,
extensions: ["htm", "html"],
index: false,
maxAge: 5000,
redirect: false,
setHeaders: function(res, _path, _stat) {
res.set("x-timestamp", Date.now());
}};


const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https=require('https');
const httpsServer=https.createServer(options,app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);
app.use(express.static("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Website/"));

app.use((req, res) => {
res.sendFile('C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Website/index.html'); 
});

httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Listening on port`+port); 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using exactly the same URL, i.e. uniroad.co.za and not something like www.uniroad.co.za? Because the latter will fail

Comment: Yes I'm using exactly the same url.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you very much. Is there aything I can do to get it secure even when using www.uniroad.co.za instead of uniroad.co.za ?

Comment: You need to get a certificate which covers these domains.